# What is the best way to allow change permissions depending of some conditions in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building an api with Django rest framework and I am using ModelViewSet with a CustomObjectPermissions and it is working fine for any user with the right permission but I want know how can I allow any user to update his own profile? I mean this user can not update other users but if the user id is the current user id he can update some columns. This user does not have any django permission, he have just access to the app.Finally, I want to use this with DjangoObjectPermissions.

Views.py here I want to allow any user update his own profile

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework import status, permissions, generics, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .serializers import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, UserSerializer
from .models import User
from authentication.permisssions import CustomObjectPermissions

class ObtainTokenPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    permission_classes = (CustomObjectPermissions,)
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import  permissions

class CustomObjectPermissions(permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions):
    """
    Similar to `DjangoObjectPermissions`, but adding 'view' permissions.
    """
    perms_map = {
        'GET': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'OPTIONS': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'HEAD': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
        'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom permission to support user can only edit their own profiles. Add following permission class in your `permissions.py`

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.created_by == request.user
```